# Discord bot runs differently when called in-file and from outside file

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to integrate a discord bot into an app such that when the user of the app does something, it calls a function that uploads something to discord. This means that the bot only has an `on_ready` function, and then a `client.close()` at the end. I wrapped the entire thing inside its own function for easy access from the main app file. Here's the code

```py
def uploader(filePath):
    homeDir = str(Path.home())
    with open(f'{homeDir}/Library/Application Support/FileBreakerApp/userInfo.json', 'r') as json_file:
        userInfo = json.load(json_file)
    bot = discord.Client()
    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        botChannel = await bot.fetch_channel(userInfo["botChannel"])
        await botChannel.send("This confirms that uploader is running")
        file = SplitFile(filePath)
        for name in file.chunkNames:
            fileObj = discord.File(
                open(f'{homeDir}/Library/Application Support/FileBreakerApp/filePieces/{name}', 'rb'),
                filename=name)
            await botChannel.send(file=fileObj)
        print("sent file")
        await botChannel.send(f'successfully uploaded:{file.fullName}')
        await bot.close()
    bot.run('CENSORED')
```

What I want it to do is after it sends "sucessfully uploaded..." it will close the bot, so the code can move on from `bot.run()` and end the method. This worked perfectly when I called the outermost function within the file it was written in, but when I called it from the main file it threw the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/nathanwolf/Documents/coding/PycharmProjects/Discord-File-Breaker/Interface.py", line 62, in uploadFile
    uploader(filename)
  File "/Users/nathanwolf/Documents/coding/PycharmProjects/Discord-File-Breaker/Uploader.py", line 27, in uploader
    bot.run('CENSORED')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 635, in run
    loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, lambda: loop.stop())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 89, in add_signal_handler
    self._check_closed()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

I read some sources saying that it had to do with enabling server members intent, so I did that on the developer portal, to no avail. Few others seem to have this problem, and one source said it had to do with `bot.close()`. Given that, here is my current theory:

> I run several others of this kind of function in the app (a bot nested in a function), all with the same token so I could run them through one bot user. By the time this runs, another function like it has been run already, with no issues. This suggests that when it closes the event loop, the next call of `bot.run` doesn't reopen it.

**How can I reopen the bot's event loop at the beginning of this function?**(`bot.start(TOKEN)` doesn't appear to work)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially need to create a new event loop before running this. You can either do this in the function or better (imo) make this an async function and create an event loop in your main file.

```py
def uploader(filePath):
    import asyncio
    
    homeDir = str(Path.home())
    with open(f'{homeDir}/Library/Application Support/FileBreakerApp/userInfo.json', 'r') as json_file:
        userInfo = json.load(json_file)
    bot = discord.Client()
    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        botChannel = await bot.fetch_channel(userInfo["botChannel"])
        await botChannel.send("This confirms that uploader is running")
        file = SplitFile(filePath)
        for name in file.chunkNames:
            fileObj = discord.File(
                open(f'{homeDir}/Library/Application Support/FileBreakerApp/filePieces/{name}', 'rb'),
                filename=name)
            await botChannel.send(file=fileObj)
        print("sent file")
        await botChannel.send(f'successfully uploaded:{file.fullName}')
        await bot.close()
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(bot.start('CENSORED')
    loop.close()
```

OR

```py
# main.py
import asyncio as aio

loop = aio.new_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(uploader("./YOUR/PATH/HERE"))
loop.close()

# your func
async def uploader(filePath):
    homeDir = str(Path.home())
    with open(f'{homeDir}/Library/Application Support/FileBreakerApp/userInfo.json', 'r') as json_file:
        userInfo = json.load(json_file)
    bot = discord.Client()
    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        botChannel = await bot.fetch_channel(userInfo["botChannel"])
        await botChannel.send("This confirms that uploader is running")
        file = SplitFile(filePath)
        for name in file.chunkNames:
            fileObj = discord.File(
                open(f'{homeDir}/Library/Application Support/FileBreakerApp/filePieces/{name}', 'rb'),
                filename=name)
            await botChannel.send(file=fileObj)
        print("sent file")
        await botChannel.send(f'successfully uploaded:{file.fullName}')
        await bot.close()
    await bot.start('CENSORED')
```

Comment: Thanks! The second option worked. However, it did seem to greatly slow down the uploading time. Any idea why?

Comment: NOTE FOR FUTURE READERS: I ended up using `aio.run()` to run the overarching async function like it was a regular function, that made it pretty fast. Similar solution, though